# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' excel error

Tags: python, excel

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

i wrote a code to add a new column and mention 2 words before a specific word and two words after for a given column of text.

I tried a code in python using nlp.

```py
import openpyxl

path5 = "C:\\Users\\AC48330\\Desktop\\my files\\FINAL.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path5)
Sheet = wb['Sheet']
y = 'you'
line = Sheet['AW']

for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['AW'], 1):
    for line in [i]:
        split_line = line.split()
    if y in split_line:
        index = split_line.index(y)
        print((' '.join(split_line[max(0, index - 2):min(index + 
                                 3,len(split_line))])), Sheet['BB'])
wb.save('finale.xlsx')
```

expected output is - word word keyword word word - in a new column

Comment: What do you think `for line in [i]:` will do?

Comment: A line in the column containing the text will be checked for the for loop

Comment: No, that is not what it does. `i` is an integer. `for line in [i]` means "iterate over the list containing the single value `i`". So your loop will execute once, and `line` will be equal to the integer `i`.